# Javascript get elements child node by data attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Given HTML of

```
<div id="parent">
   <span class="child"></span>
   <span data-text=true class="child></span>
</div>
```

How can you retrieve specifically the `<span data-text=true class="child></span>` element?

```
var ele = document.getElementById("parent")
// ele.child...
```

Note - there are many of these parent elements on the page, so once you get one you want just the data-text that is a child of the element.

Comment: Ummm `document.querySelectorAll('[data-text="true"]')` `<--` loop over that result.

Comment: Replace document by `ele`. You can use query selector from any point in the dom.

Comment: Well... `document.querySelector('#parent .child[data-text="true"]')`

Comment: @scrappedcola I specifically want it for a child element. That question is for all elements with a data value

Comment: `ele.getElementsByClassName('child')` for one. or `ele.querySelectorAll('.child')` or any other selector you need. Whether all or just child it's the same difference, just adjust where in the dom you select from.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#parent [data-text="true"]');`